# wrong arrays in matplotlib when using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a comma separated file analyzed with pandas like this:

```
datos = pd.read_csv("./data.csv",names['Functional','Rotation','Theta','gamma','hole','electron','cr12','cr21'])
```

then I want to plot a 3D surface using the data collected above, so I created this little script for that:

```
rot='A'
m1=datos.values[np.where(datos.values==rot)[0]][:,:]
print(m1)

fig =plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = np.array(m1[:,2])
y = np.array(m1[:,3])
z = np.array(m1[:,4])
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)

plt.show()
```

However, when I execute it I have the following error:

```
ValueError: x and y must be 1D arrays of the same length
```

I checked the length of the arrays and they are the same. when I "print(m1)" I got the correct list:

```
[['O3LYP' 'A' 1.0 10 3.1723 0.0312 0.2281 0.0651]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 1.0 20 2.5295 0.0111 1.0609 0.079]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 1.0 30 4.5066 0.0584 3.377 0.0629]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 1.0 40 5.2872 0.139 1.7976 0.1966]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 1.0 45 0.5049 0.1215 0.1238 0.3194]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 2.0 10 30.2506 0.0421 0.2649 0.7563]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 2.0 20 44.4919 0.0525 1.2728 0.2893]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 2.0 30 10.1271 0.0763 4.5403 1.2586]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 2.0 40 18.975 0.1421 1.46 0.3102]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 2.0 45 0.2329 0.1197 0.0839 0.2264]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 3.0 10 15.0753 0.0339 0.1594 0.4426]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 3.0 20 18.4314 0.0129 1.2087 0.0719]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 3.0 30 1.5358 0.0604 3.432 0.3222]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 3.0 40 7.423 0.1387 1.747 0.1811]
 ['O3LYP' 'A' 3.0 45 0.9319 0.1208 0.1068 0.2403]]
```

I don't really understand where is the problem. Could anyone help me find out the error, Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Could you run `x.shape` and `y.shape` and ensure that they are the same size?

Comment: Hey Antimony , I ran it and I got this (15,) (15,)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error. If `x` and `y` have the same shape, then you shouldn't be getting this error. Maybe the values in the file changed since you tested it last? Can you print `x.shape` and `y.shape` right before you execute the line? Do you still get the error when the shapes are the same?

Comment: I did it. I am getting the correct arrays but still the error is appearing, I do not  see the error

Comment: This will go the usual way. Questioner posts question without [mcve]. People comment on it for several hours without any result. Finally, questioner decides to provide a [mcve] in the question. Question will be solved some minutes later. The only unknown in the whole game is: how long will questioner wait till they post the mcve.